# Cómo actualizar los registros comprendidos entre dos fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente conjunto de datos(adjunto nada más un fragmento):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito actualizar la columna "Document no" de todos los registros V-ALB contenidos entre dos registros C-ALB consecutivos de modo que el campo "Document no" de cada V-ALB pase a contener el valor del campo "Document no" del primer C-ALB. Tal como está en la imagen todos los registros enmarcados en verde deberían contener en su columna "Document no" el valor 107001.

Os pondría código hecho por mí, pero es que no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo, por tanto no puedo proporcionar nada productivo. ¿Alguien me puede orientar cómo conseguir esto? Sería para mí una gran ayuda dados mis reiterativos intentos fallidos.

Yo haría algo así:

```
declare @num int=0

 select [item no_],[Document no_],cast([posting date] as 
 date)Fecha,[No_ series],iif(substring([no_ series],1,1)='C', 
 (select @num+=1),@num) from [Item Ledger Entry] where [item 
 no_]='cas4' and [no_ series] in ('V-ALB', 'C-ALB') order by 
 [Posting Date]
```

El problema es que no se puede incrementar una variable @num dentro de un select con campos. Independizando de ese modo los registros, luego se podría cruzar fácilmente. No sé como hacer ese conteo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo identificas esas 2 filas con C-LAB? ¿Cómo las diferencias de otras filas con el mismo valor? ¿O vas a modificar todos con cada rango?

Comment: Se diferencian por el valor de la fecha. Cada C-ALB tiene una fecha diferente, y entre ambas fechas de C-ALB consecutivos hay varios V-ALB a los que tengo que actualizar el campo "Document no" con el valor del campo "Document no" correspondiente al primer C-ALB del par, es decir, el de la fecha menor. No sé si te lo he aclarado.

Comment: Podrías poner los dato de prueba como texto?

Comment: Luis, he ampliado la publicación original.

Comment: No puedo pegar el contenido porque me lo descojona todo, no respeta el formato de tabla

Comment: Y porque queres un query y no haces un procedimiento que vayas recorriendo la tabla de a 1 registro por vez???

Comment: No @gbianchi no sugieras eso porque puede aplicarlo.

Comment: Usar cursores o bucles secuenciales, salvo excepciones, totalmente no recomendable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, necesitas obtener el rango que necesitas. Eso es sencillo mediante la función LEAD. La función LEAD nos permite obtener un valor de una fila posterior. En este caso le indicamos que sea el valor de `posting date`, una fila adelante y que ponga `9999-12-31` como fecha default si no hay más filas. La clausula `OVER` nos permite definir grupos con `PARTITION BY` y el orden que seguirán las filas con `ORDER BY`. Si además quieres agregar un número a cada rango, puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER()` que usaría la misma clausula `OVER`.

```
    SELECT [item no_],
        [Document no_],
        [posting date] AS inicio,
        LEAD( [posting date], 1, '99991231') OVER( PARTITION BY [item no_] ORDER BY [posting date]) AS fin,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [item no_] ORDER BY [posting date]) AS grupo
    FROM [Item Ledger Entry]
    WHERE [No_ series] = 'C-ALB'
```

Una vez teniendo este rango, lo podemos convertir en un CTE y hacer un JOIN con la tabla para saber cuales filas tendrán ese valor y podemos generar el UPDATE o SELECT que querramos.

```
WITH cteItemLedgetEntry AS(
    SELECT [item no_],
        [Document no_],
        [posting date] AS inicio,
        LEAD( [posting date], 1, '99991231') OVER( PARTITION BY [item no_] ORDER BY [posting date]) AS fin,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [item no_] ORDER BY [posting date]) AS grupo
    FROM [Item Ledger Entry]
    WHERE [No_ series] = 'C-ALB'
)
UPDATE ilev SET
    [Document no_] = ilec.[Document no_]
--SELECT * --Descomentar para probar
FROM [Item Ledger Entry] AS ilev
JOIN cteItemLedgetEntry AS ilec ON ilev.[item no_]     = ilec.[item no_] 
                               AND ilev.[posting date] >= ilec.inicio
                               AND ilev.[posting date] <  ilec.fin
WHERE ilev.[No_ series] = 'V-ALB';
```

Comment: Esta es una gran solucion.. pero deberias explicar que hace lead, que hace over, como usar partition by....

Comment: Justo era lo que buscaba Luis. Había probado con la función Lead y un CTE pero no supe hacer bien el JOIN. ¿Sabes cómo podría hacer la enumeración que indicaba en la consulta original? Incrementar una variable por cada aparición de una campo C-ALB

Comment: Ya agregué detalles, aunque no sé que quieres hacer con la enumeración que mencionas.